# IDXGISwapChain::CheckInterfaceSupport returns a result that cannot be

Tags: c++, c++11, directx, directx-11

According to the [`IDXGIAdapter::CheckInterfaceSupport` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174524(v=vs.85).aspx) returns `S_OK` if the passed in interface is supported and otherwise `DXGI_ERROR_UNSUPPORTED`. Code snippet:

```
for( size_t i = 0; i < GInterface::m_Adapters.size(); i++)
{
    hr = GInterface::m_Adapters.at(i)->CheckInterfaceSupport(__uuidof(ID3D11Device), (LARGE_INTEGER*)&umdVersion);
    printf( "***D3D11 %sSUPPORTED FOR ADAPTER %d (%d)",
            (hr != DXGI_ERROR_UNSUPPORTED) ? "" : "NOT ",
            i,
            umdVersion);
}
```

The console always prints `NOT`, but if I change to `__uuidof(ID3D10Device)` it does not.
But I definitely know that my GPU supports DirectX11, because:

1. The programm I am currently writing is using DirectX 11 and it's running
2. My GPU: GTX 970, not the newest, but... yeah should be supporting D3D11 :D

Can please somebody clear things up I am slightly irritated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the 'remarks' section for the `IDXGIAdapter:CheckInterfaceSupport` (emphasis mine):

> Note  You can use CheckInterfaceSupport only to check whether a
>   Direct3D 10.x interface is supported, and only on Windows Vista SP1
>   and later versions of the operating system. **If you try to use
>   CheckInterfaceSupport to check whether a Direct3D 11.x and later
>   version interface is supported, CheckInterfaceSupport returns
>   DXGI_ERROR_UNSUPPORTED**. Therefore, do not use CheckInterfaceSupport.
>   Instead, to verify whether the operating system supports a particular
>   interface, try to create the interface. For example, if you call the
>   ID3D11Device::CreateBlendState method and it fails, the operating
>   system does not support the ID3D11BlendState interface.

Comment: I have a book called introduction to DirectX 11 game programming and it has exactly that exercise in it... so I did not double check it. Thank you

Comment: Yeah, sorry my browser had an awkard error message earlier and then I forgot it, sry.